# perform linear algebra operation with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have 2 pandas series, which I perceive as column vector in linear algebra `x1` and `x2`

I want to do the operation `x1 * x2^T`, which is a column vector multiply with a row vector to produce a matrix (pandas dataframe).

What is the best procedure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `pandas`, you can go back to data frames to do it, e.g.

```
x1.to_frame().dot(x2.to_frame().T)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to import `numpy` and call:

```
pandas.DataFrame(numpy.outer(x1, x2))
```